# Unable to load multiple scenes from a primary scene in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, htc-vive

My gameplay is such that I want my scenes to perform this flow:

- Scene1 -> Scene2 -> Scene1
- Scene1 -> Scene3 -> Scene1
- Scene1 -> Scene4 -> Scene1
- Scene1 -> Scene5 -> Scene1

I have 4 different triggers leading to 4 diffferent scenes. But every time I start Scene1, the scene which gets instantiated on coming in contact with any of the triggers for the first time, just gets instantiated again no matter whichever scene the next trigger leads to.
What am I doing wrong here?
How to solve it?
[image: Triggers]

The colliders that you see in the picture above are the 4 triggers. And the code on each of these trigger is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class enter4kWorld : MonoBehaviour {

   //Orb Transform
   public GameObject targetGO;
   public GameObject otherTargetGO1;
   public GameObject otherTargetGO2;
   public GameObject otherTargetGO3;

   public Animator LightBurst;
   public GameObject Processor;
   public GameObject SceneExitGO;

   public float CountDownTimer;

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {

}

   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
   {
       if (other.tag == "GameController")
       {
           Debug.Log("Teleporter works");
           SceneExitGO.SetActive(true);

           targetGO.SetActive(true);
           otherTargetGO1.SetActive(false);
           otherTargetGO2.SetActive(false);
           otherTargetGO3.SetActive(false);
       }
   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
   {
       if (SceneExitGO.activeSelf)
       {
           //float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
           //transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);

           CountDownTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

           if (Processor.transform.position.y <= 9f)
           {
               Processor.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 1.5f, Space.World);
           }

           if (CountDownTimer <= 4.5)
           {
               LightBurst.SetTrigger("TriggerLightBurst");
           }

           if (CountDownTimer <= 0)
           {
               ChangeScene();
               CountDownTimer = 0;
           }
       }
   }

   public void ChangeScene()
   {
       SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
       //SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
   }
}
```

Comment: What are these triggers? How do they work? Please edit your question to include any relevant code or explanations.

Comment: Are you sure you don't use `SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneBuildIndex, LoadSceneMode.Additive);` somewhere? Otherwise, the scene shouldn't "get instantiated again". Also quite hard to debug it without your code being posted.

Comment: @Hilse I've shared the code as well as the picture of the colliders.
All the triggers above have similar scripts with different scenes to open up. But unfortunately only one particular scene is opening up whichever gets opened up the very first time I play after setting up the build settings and in no particular order.

Comment: @Kardux I tried using that as well but to no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a friend I came to solve this problem. The problem here is that all the scripts attached to all the triggers are similar and if you look closely, all of them contain a same public GameObject that is SceneExitGO. As soon as the SceneExitGO gets active, all the scripts attached to each trigger gets activated to perform their respective actions in Update function. This condition is called "race condition", when multiple components or scripts are running simultaneously to achieve an outcome there occurs a conflict. I solved this just by changing the public GameObject to a private Bool.

Answer (score 0):

Write yourself a real trigger that fires a UnityEvent on enter.

Have a separate MonoBehaviour that starts new scenes.

In your editor, just drag the scene starting component mentioned above onto the UnityEvent and let the event call the method that loads the next scene. Something like this:

```
public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public UnityEvent OnEnter;

    [SerializeField]
    private string tag;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag(tag) && OnEnter != null)
            OnEnter.Invoke();
    }
}
```

And here is the class to call:

```
public class SceneManagement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void LoadScene(string name) 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
    }
}
```

Note: I give no guarantee that this is without errors, I didn't check if it works, I just wrote it down out of experience. But I hope you get the concept.